# Silbentrennung von Fremdwörtern im Deutschen

Tags: loanword, hyphen

Ich habe gerade in einem Buch das Wort *Guerillakrieg* gelesen und es war zwischen den beiden L's getrennt: "Gueril-lakrieg". Ist das korrekt?

Im Spanischen würde man das *ll* ja als eigenen Buchstaben sehen oder zumindest als einen Laut, den man nicht trennen kann.

Trennt man das Wort im Deutschen nach deutschen Regeln (wie hier) oder lässt man ein Fremdwort so stehen, bzw. trennt man nach Regeln der Herkunftsprache ("Gue-ri-lla-krieg")?

Comment: Wenn ein Wort ins Deutsche übernommen wurde, so ist es vollkommen latte, wie's denn in der Quellsprache aussieht. Ich mein, es werden ja teils sogar die Schreibweisen geändert (ciao->tschau).

Comment: Die Trennung ist trotzdem etwas unglücklich. Man hätte wohl auch Guerilla-krieg trennen können.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln lassen hier recht viel Spielraum zu:

> **§ 110** Steht in einfachen oder suffigierten Wörtern zwischen Vokalbuchstaben ein einzelner Konsonantenbuchstabe, so kommt er bei der Trennung auf die neue Zeile. Stehen mehrere Konsonantenbuchstaben dazwischen, so kommt nur der letzte auf die neue Zeile.
>
> Beispiele: *Au-ge,* […] *Kom-ma,* […] *knusp-rig,* […]
>
> **§ 111** Stehen Buchstabenverbindungen wie *ch, sch; ph, rh, sh* oder *th* für
>   *einen* Konsonanten, so trennt man sie nicht. Dasselbe gilt für *ck.*
>
> Beispiele: *la-chen,* […]
>
> **§ 112** In Fremdwörtern können die Verbindungen aus Buchstaben für einen Konsonanten + *l, n* oder *r* entweder entsprechend § 110 getrennt werden, oder sie kommen ungetrennt auf die neue Zeile.
>
> Beispiele: *nob-le/no-ble, Zyk-lus/Zy-klus,* […]

Hinzu kommt, dass man das Wort verschieden ausgesprochen findet:

1. [ɡeˈriʎa] (in etwa: *Gerija*) (spanisch)
2. [ɡeˈrɪlja] (*Gerilja*) (halb-deutsch) – meiner Erfahrung nach die mit Abstand vorherrschende Aussprache im deutschen Sprachraum, im Duden gelistete Aussprache
3. [ɡəˈrɪla] (*Gerilla*) (fast ganz deutsch) oder gar [ɡʊəˈrɪla] (*Guërilla*) (ganz deutsch)

Nun können wir alles kombinieren:

- Bei Aussprache 1 greift klar § 111, da *ll* nur für einen Konsonanten (ʎ) steht, und es ist klar *Gue-ri-lla* zu trennen.
- Bei Aussprache 2 kann man nach § 110 *Gue-ril-la* trennen.
- Bei Aussprache 2 kann man nach § 112 auch *Gue-ri-lla* trennen, da das erste *l* ein »Buchstabe für einen Konsonanten« ist und somit den ersten Teil des Kriteriums erfüllt.
- Bei Aussprache 3 greift § 112 nicht mehr, da beide *l* zusammen für einen Konsonanten stehen, es greift also § 110 und die Trennung ist *Gue-ril-la* oder gar *Gu-e-ril-la.*

Inwiefern man jetzt welche Aussprachevarianten bei der Trennung berücksichtigt, muss man selbst entscheiden. Auf jeden Fall lässt die vorherrschende Aussprachevariante (2) beide Trennungen zu, sodass ich keine Variante als falsch erachten würde. Persönlich würde ich *Gue-ri-lla* bevorzugen, da es mit Aussprache 1 kompatibel ist.

Answer (score 2):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Guerillakrieg) stand es im Buch korrekt, also Gue-ril-la-krieg:

> Worttrennung: Gue|ril|la|krieg

Siehe auch:

http://de.thefreedictionary.com/Guerilla

http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Guerilla

http://www.silbentrennung24.de/?term=Guerilla

Da wir das "ll" nicht typisch deutsch aussprechen, sondern meist wie "lj", ist die Trennung an dieser Stelle unglücklich, vereinfacht aber vermutlich das Regelwerk und entsprechende Programme zur automatischen Silbentrennung. Für unglückliche Silbentrennung gibt es ja noch andere valide Beispiele: Urin-stinkt, Drucker-zeugnis, bein-halten, ...

Comment: Andererseits trennt der Duden, wenn ich mich recht entsinne, auch *Tel-to-wer,* was nach den Rechtschreibregeln klar falsch ist, da hierfür das *w* ein Konsanant sein müsste.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Und warum ist "w" kein Konsonant?

Comment: @guidot: Weil es sich hier um ein [Dehnungs-w](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehnungszeichen#Dehnungs-w_im_Digraph_-ow-) handelt.